# Want add Userid into log_message in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have set the `$config['log_threshold'] = 1;` And create the file in log folder.

And also want to show user_id as well in error log message.

```
function log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line) {

    ini_set("display_errors", "1");

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $severity = (!isset($this->levels[$severity])) ? $severity : $this->levels[$severity];

    $cid = &get_instance();

    $id = $cid->session->userdata('id');

    if (isset($id) && $id != NULL && $id != "") {

        log_message('error', 'Severity: ' . $severity . '  --> ' . $message . ' ' . $filepath . ' ' . $line . '  User_Id -> ' . $id, TRUE);

        } else {

            log_message('error', 'Severity: ' . $severity . '  --> ' . $message . ' ' . $filepath . ' ' . $line, TRUE);

        }

    }
```

But when ever i am using the `$cid->session->userdata('id')` then it throws and error stop the script.

> error message -> 
>   Notice: Undefined property: Reports::$session in C:\xampp\htdocs\Spa\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 98
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function userdata() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Spa\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 98

Thank you.

Comment: Session library not loading in core file.

Comment: Thank you sir ..... But do u have any way to dump user id into log_message ......

Comment: glad it help, can you upvote my comment?

Comment: try using hook concept in codeIgniter